# Why does TexWorks in MikTex only compile documents from a single directory?

Tags: errors, miktex, texworks

Using Portable MikTex on a Windows7 machine, my document compiles only when I save the document in my `c:\users\temp` folder. If I save the same file to my thumb drive e.g. `G:\useraa\downloads\drafts\` then I get an error message as shown in the image.

**Question:** What's so special about the directory `C:\users\temp` that allows document to compile without errors?

At one time, I was able to save .tex file to another directory and could complile. I don't know what changed.[image]

Comment: This should not be a problem. What happens when you just hit enter and let the compilation complete?

Comment: When I hit enter, the compilation completes. Is this by design?

Comment: Yes. You can provide the command-line option `-interaction=nonstopmode` to avoid stopping at errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about command line interaction modes.

Comment: @Mico This is not of topic. It is regarding how to set up Texwork to work in none interactive mode. Questions regarding Tex-editor interaction with Tex is not of topic. It is hundred of questions how to set up and use different editors (especially Vim and Emacs).